# MS Office documents won't open

Tags: 2010, iis, office

I'm using SharePoint 2010 and MS Office 2013 up until recently I was having no issues with this combination. Starting over the last week all MS Office documents will not open. The MS Office application will do 1 of 3 things:

1. Run the launch window with "opening wfeserver/library/document.docx" until the user kills the program
2. Open the program and go to a Not Responding state until the user kills the program
3. Prompt the user with:

   > sorry, we cannot open *wfeserver/library/document.docx* server isn't responding

So far, the only solution I found was to restart the IIS server on the WFE. I'm looking for what is causing this issue. is there a service or application pool that deals directly with MS Office files? Any ideas?

Note: Central Admin is running off another server. Central Admin doesn't experience the same issue only the sites on the WFE server. Also, this only affects MS Office files.

Comment: You need repare or clear the office cache.
See: [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15199/unable-to-open-office-files-in-office-client][1]


  [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15199/unable-to-open-office-files-in-office-client

Comment: I would agree with this but the issue is effecting all the users not just myself. An IIS restart fixes it so I'm assuming something is getting stuck

Answer (score -3):

start task manager, and end-task called MSOSYNC.EXE

Comment: This was something affecting all users at the same time not just a handful at different times. What I did to resolve the issue was set a IIS to refresh its connections every 2 hours.